# Commutation relation coherent states

Tags: operators, commutator, coherent-states

I am reading p. 159, chapter 4 of [Condensed Matter Field Theory](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/condensed-matter-field-theory/10A853D7E703F3BB311B4C02FC91868F) and I don't really get this commutation relation: They want to show that $\left[\hat{a}_i,\hat{a}_j^\dagger\right] = \delta_{ij}$. The operators are defined as $\hat{a}_i |\phi\rangle = \phi_i |\phi\rangle$ and $\hat{a}_i^\dagger |\phi\rangle = \partial_{\phi_i} |\phi\rangle$ while $|\phi\rangle=\exp\left(\sum_i \phi_i \hat{a}_i^\dagger\right) |0\rangle$.

What they did to show that is: $\left[\hat{a}_i,\hat{a}_j^\dagger\right] |\phi\rangle = \left( \partial_{\phi_j} \phi_i - \phi_i \partial_{\phi_j} \right) |\phi\rangle = \delta_{ij} |\phi\rangle$. Why isn't it $\left[\hat{a}_i,\hat{a}_j^\dagger\right] |\phi\rangle = \left(\phi_i \partial_{\phi_j}  - \partial_{\phi_j} \phi_i  \right) |\phi\rangle$?

For clarification: If I just apply the operators myself, I don't get the result the book gets.$\left[\hat{a}_i,\hat{a}_j^\dagger\right] |\phi\rangle = \hat{a}_i \hat{a}_j^\dagger |\phi\rangle - \hat{a}_j^\dagger \hat{a}_i |\phi\rangle = \left(\phi_i \partial_{\phi_j}  - \partial_{\phi_j} \phi_i  \right) |\phi\rangle$ My solution has a $-1$ attached to it.

Comment: If $|\phi\rangle=\exp\left(\sum_i \phi_i \hat{a}_i\right) |0\rangle|\phi\rangle=\exp\left(\sum_i \phi_i \hat{a}_i\right) |0\rangle$ then $\partial_{\phi_i} |\phi\rangle =\hat{a}_i|\phi\rangle $

Comment: I forgot the dagger in the coherent states' definition. I edited it.

Answer (score 2):

Denote : $ |\{\phi_{i}^{}\}\rangle = e_{}^{\sum_{i}^{}\phi_{i}^{} \hat{a}_{i}^{\dagger}}|\text{vac}\rangle $.

$\textbf{Note :}$
$$\hat{a}_{i}^{}\hat{a}_{j}^{\dagger}|\{\phi_{i}^{}\}\rangle = \hat{a}_{i}^{}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_{j}^{}}|\{\phi_{i}^{}\}\rangle = \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_{j}^{}} \hat{a}_{i}^{} |\{\phi_{i}^{}\}\rangle = \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_{j}^{}} \phi_{i}^{} |\{\phi_{i}^{}\}\rangle $$
and
$$\hat{a}_{j}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{i}^{} |\{\phi_{i}^{}\}\rangle = \hat{a}_{j}^{\dagger}\phi_{i}^{}|\{\phi_{i}^{}\}\rangle = \phi_{i}^{} \hat{a}_{j}^{\dagger} |\{\phi_{i}^{}\}\rangle = \phi_{i}^{} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_{j}^{}} |\{\phi_{i}^{}\}\rangle .$$

Comment: Why can you just swap the positions of the annihilation operator and the derivative?

Comment: As $[\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_{j}^{}},\hat{a}_{i}^{}]=0$.

Comment: Is this also true for i=j?

Comment: Operators $\{\hat{a}_{i}^{}\}$ and $\{\hat{a}_{i}^{\dagger}\}$ are all independent of $\{\phi_{i}^{}\}$ (set of parameters used to label eigenstates of $\hat{a}_{i}^{}$'s).